# Get people that have marked a question as a duplicate to review it since changes have been made

Tags: support, flagging, duplicate-questions, comments

I have a question [When testing is it OK to use a method of the subject to test another method of the subject?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/270520/when-testing-is-it-ok-to-use-a-method-of-the-subject-to-test-another-method-of-t)

This isn't a duplicate of *[Is there any value in writing a unit test that is a subset of another test?]* and I have taken the necessary steps to make the people that marked it as a duplicate aware of this. Including selecting the correct answer, commenting suggesting why it isn't, adding a description to the bottom on my question and flagging the question. Still it remains a "duplicate".

What should I do next? (I have even contacted stack exchange directly asking them to allow me to explain to the people that marked it as a duplicate why it isn't.

Comment: Adding **IS NOT THE SAME QUESTION AND DOES NOT ANSWER THIS QUESTION** at the top of your question isn't going to help, and it might even discourage people from taking a closer look at it. Instead, how about you update your question to _explain_ how your question is different, and _why_ the duplicate doesn't answer it? Btw, I don't mean to say that the questions are indeed duplicates (I don't have a fully formed opinion yet), I'm just saying that there are a lot more effective ways of helping people to see that they aren't.

Comment: If you notice at the bottom of the question this has been explained I can move the information at the bottom higher underneath the bold text. 

@Yannis The reason for adding the bold this is not the same question is because I received some advice to place "I've read [question here] and it does not answer [my actual question]" in the title but because the characters are limited to 150 this isn't possible in my situation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you see something that doesn't agree with you on this site with regards to content or user actions, then please flag for a community moderator.  That is why we are here so that you don't have to go to StackExchange directly with questions like this.  If something we see needs to be addressed that is outside of our control then we will contact StackExchange if it is needed.

I don't believe this is a duplicate after looking at both questions and decided to reopen it.  The community may yet still decide to close it again if they feel I made a wrong decision here but lets give it another try.

Also in the future, try not to edit questions or answers with meta-commentary about the question or answer.  This kind of information is for the comments area or for a greater discussion you can go to Meta.

Comment: worth noting that timely edits [automatically push questions into reopen review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078/165773) without moderator involvement

Answer (score 2):

A simple and clear edit of the question is enough to bounce it back to the front page or active questions. Clear and professional writing will get people to read past the first lines that show up in the summary for the question. If it is clear that the question is not a duplicate through the wording of the question (rather than argumentative text at the top), the question will likely get a reopen vote which will put it back in the reopen review queue.  A revision that clearly shows that the question is not a duplicate (rather than arguments that it is not) is much more likely to garner the necessary reopen reviews.

---

When an edit to a question is made, it goes into the reopen review. If previous revisions were made and reopen review said no, it would take a reopen vote to kick it into the queue.

The reviewers will see something like https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/129650 that shows the most recent revision to the question.

The revision for yours that would have made it into the reopen queue would look like:

[image]

The February 12th 2015 revision is the one that should have kicked it into the queue. I don't see it in there currently (as of this writing, 10k tools revision history [page 75](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/history?page=75) would have it)

That said, the key question that I have when I look at a reopen review is "is this post one that should be open ***in its current state***?"  And looking at that post, the answer is quite simply "no".  It would take a bit of editing with someone who appears to be angry and likes to use all caps bold. That isn't a situation that I want to engage in - I've gotten my ear chewed off far too many times in the past for me to want to get into fixing the question based on that revision.  Such content makes it one that I am much more likely to cast a delete vote on because I don't have the time to moderate it than to cast a reopen vote.  I am much more likely to work with a calm professional than someone who is going to yell.

Yes, I did go back in after it was reopened (and accidently overwrote Maple's edit - rollbacks do that) and rolled it back to the latest version that didn't have any meta bits in it.

Ideally, when one wants to say "this isn't a duplicate" - the process isn't to write **IT IS NOT THE SAME QUESTION** at the top, but rather to seamlessly write the question so that it clearly isn't a duplicate. This should be done without writing 'edit:' in the middle of the body - the post is one comprehensive whole that shouldn't need to be bounced up and down from comment to question and back again.  Write the question clearly and as professionally as one would expect to find on MSDN or similar documentation - that is how to get a question reopened.